# File plugin not working with PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've been battling with this for a while. I haven't found many other people with this problem, and the ones I did find, didn't have the File plugin installed.

In my case, the File plugin is installed as a dependency of File-Transfer.

**Problem:** When I build and install the application directly from my PC to my Android device, everything works fine, but when it's built with PhoneGap Build, it doesn't work.

**What happens:** In app.initialize(), I call cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        initApp();
        alert(1);
        alert(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory);
        alert(2);
    }
};
```

When I build and install locally, all three alerts are shown, and the directory path is correct, but when it's built by PhoneGap Build `alert(1);` is shown, but the second two calls aren't. This leads me to believe that cordova.file is undefined.

I've tried using PhoneGap Build's remote debugging tool, but nothing seems to print in the console, despite the documentation saying it should.

Here are the plugins installed:
[image]

And here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "id-removed"
        version   = "0.0.0">

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />

    <name>Name removed</name>

    <description>
        Description removed.
    </description>

    <author email="email removed" href="removed">
        Removed
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />

    <access origin="*" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.9"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" version="0.2.6"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.5"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.2"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.7"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" version="0.2.6"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.7"/>
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" version="0.7.4"/>
</widget>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the error log you have when the error occurs? You can check it either with logcat or activating debug in phonegap build and using weinre to debug the app.

Comment: I haven't tried logcat, but I tried weinre. I was never able to get it to work. The device connected, but nothing was ever written in the console, even when I added console.log() calls for testing.

Comment: I finally managed to get weinre working, but there no error is shown. "1" is printed to the console, but that's it.

Comment: why don't you try to install the plugin and don't trust it's installed as a dependency?

Comment: I have tried that, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just understand what were under my eyes hours ago :

[In the official documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#where-to-store-files) , it said :

> **As of v1.2.0**, URLs to important file-system directories are provided. [...]

While you are using the phonegap build platform to build your project, where the **latest available version is 1.0.1**

See there : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/617

Will this situation, `cordova.file` will remain `undefined`.

Phonegap build seems encounter some difficulties to upgrade the plugins, even the core plugins.

Comment: Ohhh yes I see. I remember reading that too, but didn't put two and two together when looking at the versions. Thanks a lot! I ended up using another solution entirely with Google App Engine and Python, but I'm glad you found the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var debugFilePlugin = function(){
    try{
        if (cordova.file && typeof(cordova.file == 'object')) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(cordova.file));
            if (cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory) {
                alert(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory);
            }
        } else {
            alert('cordova.file is a ' + typeof cordova.file + ' value.');
        }
    } catch(e){
        var t = typeof e ;
        if(t == "object") {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        } else if (t == "string") {
            alert(e);
        } else {
            alert("typeof e =" + t);
        }
    }        
};

debugFilePlugin();
```

Comment: Thank you. That confirms what I suspected - "cordova.file is a undefined value." And now I've learned a new debugging method, so thanks for that; however, I don't understand why it's undefined. The plugin is definitely installed.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and had no difficulties because ... I have the exact same one. I am trying to understand the problem. How did you create your project ? Using cordova-cli ? phonegap-cli ? In wich version ? Did you updated it since the creation of your project ?

Comment: Well the local project I have was created using Cordova CLI, version 3.5.0. I have not updated Cordova since the creation of the project. I just noticed that my PhoneGap Build config.xml has version 3.3.0; although I don't know why that would make a difference since all PhoneGap Build requires is the web files, not the actual project files created by the Cordova CLI.